# Runtime Conversions of JVM calls to DVM calls

Tags: android, jvm, runtime, bytecode, dalvik

I am not an android-app developer but a (proficient) java-apps developer.

I have learnt from many different sources that `.class(bytecodes)` files are converted into `.dex` files.
Also I have learnt that java applets do not run on android devices (obviously because of absence of JRE).

Some android applications are also available online that can convert `.class -> .dex` and then can run those simple programs on devices.

I wanted to a author a project (hopefully in java but other language will not be a problem) that can covert `JVM` calls to `DVM` calls in runtime.

This will solve a lot of unseen problems and also that associated with java applets on android browsers.

Please guide me.

Comment: That isn't likely to work. Among other problems, they use different runtime libraries and different security models.

Comment: One complication i recently dealt into. An Android Developer just told me that DVM can be understood as Decompressor + JRE where 'Decompressor' for `.dex -> .class(one or many)` and JRE to interpret those `.class` files

Comment: It can be understood that way, but that's not how it's actually implemented.